# Domain Mapping with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, dns

I have been trying to develop a domain mapping service using Zend. So, I need to access the $_SERVER['HOST'] parameter during preDespatch , but If I var_dump($_SERVER) in a Plugin's preDispatch() function it does return NULL. Can someone tip off where to do that or how ?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad , should have looked for 'HTTP_HOST' rather than 'HOST'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` that you want, you can try this:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
    $request->getHttpHost();
}
```